# react firebase login with google

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to have a authentication in react with firebase. When I try to sign in, the googleauth provider pops up but is always blank. It was working before but now it is not working

```js
import firebase from 'firebase'
import { auth } from '../firebase.js'
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core'
   
   
function SignIn() {
   function signInWithGoogle() {
       const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
       auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
   }
   return (
       <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', height: '100vh', alignItems: 'center' ,backgroundColor: '#e3e7ea',width: '100vw',}}>
               <div style={{textAlign: 'center',color:"#708090"}}>
                   <h1>Chat it!</h1>
                   <button className="btn" onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign In With Google</button>
               </div>
           </div>
       )
   }
   
export default SignIn
```

Answer (score 0):

If you said it was working well before, try

```
signInWithRedirect
```

instead of:

```
signInWithPopup
```

To see if the problem is about popup blocking by the browser or not.